# question about uniformly continuity

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

If $f$: $D$-->$E$ and $g$: $E$-->$R$ are uniformly continuous, is $g º f$: $D$-->$R$ also uniformly continuous?

I think it is also uniformly continuous but I don't know how to write reasoning. can I say since the composite of two continuous functions is continuous? but it does not show that the composite is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $\eta >0$ such that $d(g(u),g(v)) <\epsilon$ if $d(u,v) <\eta$. There exists $\delta >0$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) <\eta$ if $d(x,y) <\delta$. Can you finish?

Comment: i'll try it. i'll post my attempt, can you review it?

Comment: I posted my attempt above!

Comment: @raydiiii What you have done is fine.